# How to animate the alpha of a textLabel in UITableView?

Tags: swift, ios8, uiviewanimation

Hey guys I am trying to change the alpha of the default taxtLabel from a UITableView when the table is scrolled but I am getting this error:

```
Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type '(FloatLiteralConvertible, animations: () -> () -> $T2)'
```

My code is this:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            cell.textLabel??.alpha = 0.0
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an empty `return` statement at the end of the closure

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
    cell.textLabel??.alpha = 0.0
    return // <== add this
})
```

You are using the compact (shortened) closure version, which has implicit return. What happens is that your code is read by the compiler as:

```
return cell.textLabel??.alpha = 0.0
```

and that doesn't match the closure signature, hence the compilation error. Adding the return statement makes it explicit that the closure has no return value.

Comment: would adding the ', completion: nil' part of the animateWithDuration method not make a difference as well? My labels all seem to animate their alpha fine with that part included and no explicit return... Or am I missing something? haha